# Laravel, Mysql duplicate entry

Tags: mysql, laravel-5

I am using Laravel 5. I am facing a problem while creating a new Member - system finds an existing entry and crashes.

Is there any Laravel/PHP way to verify if Member already exists before creation and update just updated_at timestamp?

```
$member = new Member(['group' => 1, 'user_id' => 1]);
$member->save();
```

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '1-1' for key 'MEMBER_GROUP';

Comment: use `Member::updateOrCreate([$findProps, $updateProps])`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [laravel updateOrCreate method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42695943/laravel-updateorcreate-method)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to look into Laravel's [updateOrCreate](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#other-creation-methods) method.
So you will do something like:

```
Member::updateOrCreate(['group' => 1, 'user_id' => 1], []);
```

This will try to find a user with `user_id` 1 and `group` 1, if it doesn't find it, it will create it for you otherwise it will just update it.

In your case, I have given the update array as `[]` as you will not need to update anything if the match is found.